# Angular 5 , when path is empty redirectTo ignored or not working

Tags: angular

i'm using angular 5 for my first application. my actual probleme is when i try the empty path i'm not redirected to  a dashboard like i want but i'm redirected to an empty page.i will shard the routes of my application.

**I just want to be redirected to the dashboard
 from the url http: // localhost: 4200**

PS :sorry for my bad english

**AppRoutes :**

```
 export const AppRoutes: Routes = [

     { path: "", component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

     { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },

  {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [

            {
                path: 'components',
                loadChildren: './components/components.module#ComponentsModule'
            }, {
                path: 'forms',
                loadChildren: './forms/forms.module#Forms'
            }, {
                path: 'tables',
                loadChildren: './tables/tables.module#TablesModule'
            }, {
                path: 'widgets',
                loadChildren: './widgets/widgets.module#WidgetsModule'
            }, {
                path: 'charts',
                loadChildren: './charts/charts.module#ChartsModule'
            }, {
                path: 'calendar',
                loadChildren: './calendar/calendar.module#CalendarModule'
            },

           {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './userpage/user.module#UserModule'
            }, {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './timeline/timeline.module#TimelineModule'
            }, 


        ]},


];
```

**DashboardRoutes**

```
export const DashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                children: [{
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    component: DashboardComponent,
                    canActivate: [UrlPermission],
                }]
            },
        ]
    }];
```

**Other Routes(SettingRoutes)**

```
export const SettingRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'settings',
                children: [ {
                    path: 'myprofile',
                    component: MyaccountComponent,
                    canActivate: [UrlPermission],
                    data: {
                        rightPage: ['right_of_access_to_the_my_account_page']
                    }
                }]}
            ]
    }

];
```